# How to sum up all rows except the 1st which is a factor

Tags: r

I have this simple data frame:

```
>fruits 
 X Apple Banana Orange
1 1   5.2    5.0    4.2
2 2   2.6    4.4    3.7
3 3   2.7    2.4    2.7
4 4   4.0    1.3    6.2
5 5   6.5    3.1    4.1
6 6   4.2    3.8    5.4

>str(fruits)
'data.fram e':  6 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X     : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ Apple : num  5.2 2.6 2.7 4 6.5 4.2
 $ Banana: num  5 4.4 2.4 1.3 3.1 3.8
 $ Orange: num  4.2 3.7 2.7 6.2 4.1 5.4
```

I need to sum all rows except the first column which is a factor. I tried to loop:

```
>for(i in 1:nrow(fruits)) {fruits$total[i] <- sum(fruits[i,-1])} print (fruits$total)

Error: unexpected symbol in "for(i in 1:nrow(fruits)) {fruits$total[i] <-         sum(fruits[i,-1])} print"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `rowSums(fruits[,-1])`?

Comment: R is complaining because there is not line break or `;` in front of the `print` statement.

Comment: @Ronald it gives [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: With the data you show here it wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If @Roland wishes to post the answer I'll remove this.  But yes, `rowSums` is definitely the way I'd do it.

Set up data to match yours:

```
> fruits <- read.table(h=T, text = "X Apple Banana Orange
   1 1   5.2    5.0    4.2
   2 2   2.6    4.4    3.7
   3 3   2.7    2.4    2.7
   4 4   4.0    1.3    6.2
   5 5   6.5    3.1    4.1
   6 6   4.2    3.8    5.4")
> fruits$X <- as.factor(fruits$X)
> sapply(fruits, class)
#        X     Apple    Banana    Orange 
# "factor" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Get the row sums of the non-factor columns specific to your data set:

```
> rowSums(fruits[-1])
#    1    2    3    4    5    6 
# 14.4 10.7  7.8 11.5 13.7 13.4
```

Or (even better) for if you do not know where the factor columns are in the data, you can remove them in the calculation with the logical negation of `is.factor`

```
> rowSums(fruits[!sapply(fruits, is.factor)])
#    1    2    3    4    5    6 
# 14.4 10.7  7.8 11.5 13.7 13.4
```

Keep in mind that the last line will remove **all** factor columns from calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar topic as author but wanted to remain within my table for the calculation, therefore I landed on specifiying the column names to use in `rowSums()` as a solution as follow:

```
fruits %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(.[setdiff(names(.),"X")]))

#   X Apple Banana Orange  sum
# 1 1   5.2    5.0    4.2 14.4
# 2 2   2.6    4.4    3.7 10.7
# 3 3   2.7    2.4    2.7  7.8
# 4 4   4.0    1.3    6.2 11.5
# 5 5   6.5    3.1    4.1 13.7
# 6 6   4.2    3.8    5.4 13.4
```